# Why the value of parameter DWORD reco from IRichEditOleCallback::GetClipboardData is always RECO_COPY?

Tags: drag-and-drop, visual-c++, richedit

I thought the value of reco should be RECO_DRAG when I dragged sth. in my richedit, but in fact it always RECO_COPY. Is that normal or I had made mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

Note:  I work for Microsoft.

Thank you for bringing this to our attention.  We've filed a bug on the following issues surrounding this.  It may get fixed someday, but we're calling this a documentation bug.  RECO_DRAG doesn't appear to be supported at any level, and RECO_DROP appears to be supported only in QueryAcceptData.

The documentation update bug concerns the following functions (of note:  QueryAcceptData also uses a similar parameter but it's documented properly).

---

Page:  IRicheditOle::GetClipboardData
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774341(v=vs.85).aspx

Change:
Update the reco parameter description, removing the table and just say that it's not used.

---

Page:  IRichEditOleCallback::GetClipboardData
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774315(v=vs.85).aspx

Change:
Update the reco parameter description, removing everything but RECO_COPY and RECO_CUT.  This means removing RECO_DRAG, RECO_DROP and RECO_PASTE.

Comment: Thx for your answer but,why RECO_DRAG isn't supported? I intended to do different things when users' operation was drag or copy,for example, I only update data in clip board when user copy but not drag sth. I think it is useful.